# Is it way, way too easy to contribute to "Documentation"

Tags: discussion, documentation

For some reason I thought I'd spend a few hours helping on the "coroutines" section of "Unity" in Documentation. Fair enough.

Almost everything there was complete crap.  (In computing, Unity is the example nonpareil of "garbage you can find on the web".)

Now, on the beloved SO QA site, **it's no problem at all** that 90% of everything there is garbage. On any QA on SO, you get 9x eager amateurs (writing nonsense) and then 1x awesome engineer will come along and provide astounding information.  That's great - and it's **no problem just flicking through the garbage**.  That's the nature of SO and why we love SO.

But.

Isn't "Documentation" meant to be more, let's say, definitive .. professional .. expert .. curated .. vetted?

So: after an SO QA page has been there for a year, you get the usual situation: there's 90% amateurish wrong junk - which is fine, wonderful, go libertarians! - that's the hurly burly of SO; and there's 10% outstanding amazing life-changing excellence.  Fantastic. There's all the room in the world, on SO, for people with no clue who want to see themselves in print - voila.

But.

In a word, shouldn't there be something on Documentation like, you *can't even post* unless you have 100,000 points, or the like?

You can see where you could tie it in to your "badges" system, say.

(So, you can't have anything to do with Documentation until you have ten "Great Answer"s and ten "Famous Question"s.)

Another thing ... imagine on the traditional SO site.  You know how you can vote up, star, and so on.  You could have a new button: "This person is **Good Enough for Documentation**."  (And you can't even click that unless you have 5 ticked anwsers in that tag, or some such.)  Almost something like choosing moderators, you know?  So a writer has to collect 10 **Good Enough for Documentation**s before they can mess about on Documentation, you know?

At the very least could you guys at least do something like, you can't touch Documentation until you have 20 ticked answers, or the like?

Imagine this ..

**think how good you'd feel going to Documentation, if, you knew that every single writer there had ten "Great Answer"s and ten "Famous Question"s.  Nice right?**

Comment: "go libertarians"? Anyway, I'm not seeing anything here that hasn't already be said, say, here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339902/215552, or here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329940/215552, or here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329191/215552, or here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328978/215552, etc., etc.

Comment: Plenty of existing discussion on that, e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334638/documentation-is-on-its-way-to-becoming-the-next-w3schools (I don't think junk lying around is "libertarian" under any interpretation of that very broad term btw...)

Comment: I think SO wants everyone to be able to contribute, just like in Q&A. Problem is that quality control is mostly done by a review queue; and to make it worse, it takes a mere 100 rep to be able to review. My recommendation would be to raise that bar **and** make the audits much harder.

Comment: ?  are you trying to say it should be "marked for deletion as a duplicate" ..?  If so, why not do that?

Comment: hi @S.L.Barth - gotchya, I just learned about the humourous "100" issue in an answer below.  OK, so "Documentation" was an astounding waste of my time.  More fool me. Thanks for taking the time to explain, guys

Comment: More like asking "where the heck have you been for the last 6 months while the rest of Meta has been discussing this to death?" Or maybe "Is there something wrong that you can't search?"...

Comment: 100K to post?! Me thinks you added one zero too many. There are only 445 users with that much rep on the whole site! Also, the people most active on Unity tag: yourself, programmer etc, don't even have that much...

Comment: hi @code11.  think *how good* the "Documentation" product would be, if that was the case. anyway this seems to have been deleted as a dupe - cheers

Answer (score 8):

I really don't post too many answers. They rarely get upvoted.

I still know stuff about Java that isn't documented here.

Why should I be barred from helping out? Honestly, the real problem is the garbage that gets through review, and there are a lot of people saying that we should raise the requirements for reviewing to 500 rep (or higher), where the other queues are.

Comment: "raise the requirements for reviewing to 500 rep" .. if you mean requirement for reviewing changes on Documentation ... yes.  You're saying there is NO REP REQUIREMENT at the moment?  you're kidding right?

Comment: @JoeBlow there is—but it's only 100, which means that anyone who has avid user status on any SE site can come in and review things they have no clue about.

Comment: I mean - you're totally serious right?  That's just a straightforward bug.

Comment: What an astonishing waste of my time.

Comment: @JoeBlow IIRC the 100 point threshold was used because that is the amount of rep needed to edit Community Wiki posts. The idea was probably that Docs was a kind of CW. I for one do not think that it is, and would only let tag-badge holders review. As rep is a terrible yardstick for reviewer ability anyway.

Comment: It's so astoundingly silly it's not worth discussing.  I mean, I addressed an issue that maybe 4 other experts in the Unity tag, and maybe 50 living humans, even understand the topic under discussion.  And three folks who literally have never seen a Unity QA "approve" it?  Again, thanks for your time in clarifying how it all works - cheers!  Thanks again

Comment: *"I really don't post too many answers."* Why not? *"They rarely get upvoted."* Why not?

Comment: @CodyGray: We've talked to programmers who are interested in using Stack Overflow, but don't answer much because there's so much competition to answer questions on the most popular tags. Questions that aren't quickly answered are often either impossible to answer or so obscure nobody comes back to upvote. Probably folks should be a bit more bold about answering questions, but that's sometimes discouraged in comments. Documentation's more collaborative environment solves some of those problems. It might also be a way for programmers to get confidence to wade into answers too.